# How to use sql function for a computed column to retrieve a value from XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a `XML` column and save XML like this to it:

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>   
</Employees>
```

I want to have another table with a columns that in it I use a function to retrieve value of `Name` element from every row.such this :

```
  Id           Name
  -----------------
  1            Nima
  2            Agha
  ...          ...
```

How I can do this?

thanks

Comment: Sorry don't understand the question. Please specify your problem.

Comment: Do you need to get values from both Name and LName nodes? And what ids should be for next Person node?

Comment: I want to convert my XML Data to relational and columny data.First I'd like to do this by view that then I'd like to create index over my view but It has not this feature.now I want to convert my xml data to columns that I can use index over columns

Comment: @Dalex :I just need get value of `Name` element and persist it to a column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetName(@xml XML)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @xml.value('/Employees[1]/Person[1]/Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
END
GO
SELECT dbo.GetName(CAST(N'
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>   
</Employees>' AS XML))
```

**But**

you have to provide the connection between your `Id` field from second table to xml field from the first

Comment: Ok,thanks but How I can use this with columns Default value? please read my question again.I can query XML columns...

Comment: `CREATE TABLE blabla(xmlcolumn xml, name nvarchar(max) default dbo.GetName(xmlcolumn))`

Comment: thanks ,1 step forward but I want to use this value in another table

Comment: That's why I said that you **have to** provide some more information how to connect these tables

Answer (score 5):

Try to use a table valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTableFromXML(@xml XML)
RETURNS @retXMLTable TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Name nvarchar(max) NULL, 
    LName nvarchar(max) NULL, 
)AS
BEGIN
 INSERT @retXMLTable (ID,FirstName,LName)
 select @xml.value('/Employees[1]/Person[1]/ID[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        @xml.value('/Employees[1]/Person[1]/Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') 
        @xml.value('/Employees[1]/Person[1]/LName [1]', 'nvarchar(max)') 
 RETURN;
END;
```

Generally same as the answer from Oleg, but you couuld work with the result as a table. If you recreate the sample you get get all your entries from the xml table at once.